# transmission-daemon web interface

Tags: apache2, bittorrent, transmission

I'm set up transmission-daemon on my remote server.
But I can't to make RPC (web interface) work.

//Ubuntu server 10.04.3 LTS

Here is my config

> /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/settings.json

```
{
    "alt-speed-down": 50,
    "alt-speed-enabled": false,
    "alt-speed-time-begin": 540,
    "alt-speed-time-day": 127,
    "alt-speed-time-enabled": false,
    "alt-speed-time-end": 1020,
    "alt-speed-up": 50,
    "bind-address-ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
    "bind-address-ipv6": "::",
    "blocklist-enabled": false,
    "dht-enabled": true,
    "download-dir": "/home/***/torrents/shared/",
    "download-limit": 100,
    "download-limit-enabled": 0,
    "encryption": 1,
    "incomplete-dir": "/home/***/torrents/incomplete/",
    "incomplete-dir-enabled": true,
    "lazy-bitfield-enabled": true,
    "max-peers-global": 200,
    "message-level": 2,
    "open-file-limit": 32,
    "peer-limit-global": 240,
    "peer-limit-per-torrent": 60,
    "peer-port": 51000,
    "peer-port-random-high": 65535,
    "peer-port-random-low": 49152,
    "peer-port-random-on-start": false,
    "peer-socket-tos": 0,
    "pex-enabled": true,
    "port-forwarding-enabled": false,
    "preallocation": 1,
    "proxy": "",
    "proxy-auth-enabled": false,
    "proxy-auth-password": "",
    "proxy-auth-username": "",
    "proxy-enabled": false,
    "proxy-port": 80,
    "proxy-type": 0,
    "ratio-limit": 2.0000,
    "ratio-limit-enabled": false,
    "rename-partial-files": true,
    "rpc-authentication-required": false,
    "rpc-bind-address": "0.0.0.0",
    "rpc-enabled": true,
    "rpc-password": "",
    "rpc-port": 9091,
    "rpc-username": "",
    "rpc-whitelist": "",
    "rpc-whitelist-enabled": false,
    "speed-limit-down": 100,
    "speed-limit-down-enabled": false,
    "speed-limit-up": 100,
    "speed-limit-up-enabled": false,
    "umask": 18,
    "upload-limit": 100,
    "upload-limit-enabled": 0,
    "upload-slots-per-torrent": 14,
    "watch-dir": "/home/***/torrents/job/",
    "watch-dir-enabled": true
}
```

I tried setting username, password, add my ip to whitelist, set `*.*.*.*` to whitelist,
toggle whitelist-enabled parameter, but on

```
*IP*:9091
or
*IP*:9090/transmission/web/
```

there is

> Unable to connect Firefox can't establish a connection to the server
>   at *IP*:9091.

Here is `netstat -antup | grep 9091`

> tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:9091 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 9158/transmission-d

and `iptables -L`

> ACCEPT tcp --  anywhere  anywhere  tcp dpt:9091

I have apache2 on 80 port and it's works good (maybe it's interfere)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was DMZ on remote server. Closed

Comment: If this is closed then please select this as the answer so SO thinks it is solved as well.